# MySQL: Query that filters the results

Tags: php, mysql

I wish I could make a query that filters the results. It works when I make this request alone:

```
SELECT * FROM products_details WHERE active = '1' AND category LIKE '% Phobies%';
```

But in my code, when test, I have this error that appears every time:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE [42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' in C: \ laragon \ www
>   \ tresorsdufutur \ ajax.php on line 36

But I do not have an IN in my query and all the terms come from the same column. I really can not find or find my mistake. Here is my code

```
$ query = "SELECT * FROM products_details WHERE active = '1'";

if (isset ($ category) &&! empty ($ category)) {
$ categorydata = implode ("','", $ category);
$ query. = "AND product_category LIKE (`$categorydata`) ";
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is weird that you use space character between `$` and variable name. Nevertheless, what is the value of `$category` variable ?

Comment: Why do you have backticks around `$ categorydata` ?

Comment: original query `category LIKE ...`  php query `product_category LIKE` those are 2 different column names :-)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `echo $query;` so we see the query you have built with your code.

Comment: For the space between the $ and categorydata it's my mistake in copying my query. It should have been written like that $ categorydata :) I corrected my code

Comment: on screenshot it says `product_categorie IN` It seem you are doing many things same time. Stop doing that. Do 1 thing and ask 1 thing. Don't apply changes all over. Your environment should be stable and trustful when anybody is trying to help you.

Comment: @Alex I know he's telling me that, but the problem is that I do not use IN at all! This is where I get lost. Where will he find the IN?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I use backticks because some terms have single quotation marks in french

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a few things that could cause problems

1. You seem to be missing a space between the two parts of the query that you are concatenating
2. You are using ` as quotation marks in the latter part of the query
3. It's been a while since I did PHP but I think you need to concatenate `$categorydata`

Try this

```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM products_details WHERE active = '1'";

   if (isset($category) && !empty($category)) {
     $categorydata = implode ("','", $category);
     $query. = " AND product_category IN ('". $categorydata. "') ";
   }
```

Comment: it does not work unfortunately. I always have the same mistake.

Comment: Well, anyway, I don't know what you are doing but it looks like it could be open for SQL injections. Look into  using prepared statements or perhaps an ORM.